# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How to pass parameters to create_engine() such as pool_size?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

A noob's confused question:

How and where to set pool_size?

I found setting the pool size in docs as:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://me@localhost/mydb',
                       pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
```

, but is there a way to set pool_size for below snippet too,if yes pleased to know how?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/testdb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
    ......
    ......
```

error is as follows:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using >= version 2.4, the `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` key exists specifically for specifying keyword arguments that will be passed to `create_engine` ([docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#configuration)). So in your case adding `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {"pool_size": 20}` to your app configuration should do the trick.

Alternatively, you can pass the dict of keyword arguments to the `engine_options` parameter of the `SQLAlchemy()` constructor ([docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#configuration)), e.g., `SQLAlchemy(app, engine_options={"pool_size": 20})` is equivalent to above, except that these values will merge with and take precedence over any engine settings also defined in `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS`.

Finally, there are a suite of `SQLALCHEMY_` prefixed configuration keys that are depreciated, but will work until 3.0. In this case `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE"] = 20`. Unless you are using a version earlier than 2.4, it would be better to use one of the former options.

Comment: I don't understand why this error is thrown,`sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30`.....how can I avoid this , why it is limited to 10, what is the concept here, I just try to refresh the page for 15 or so then automatically the error rises, sorry this is new to me

Comment: I thought it was due to pool size limit, but I have changed it to 20 and I guess this has nothing to do with timeout

Comment: The way that you framed your question wasn't really asking for an answer to that, rather you just asked how to configure the pool size, which I've answered. You need to work out why your application isn't releasing connections back to the pool. As it stands, there isn't enough info in this question to answer that. If you need additional help, please ask a new question (don't edit this one) and try to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have asked the timeout question here mate, if you have any idea please do help me.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183289/how-to-overcome-the-connection-timed-out-error